# Does my Mac App need to apply Network Access entitlement key?

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, entitlements

My mac app has a built-in browser for watching streaming video, so do I need a Client Access entitlement key ("Allow Outgoing Connections: com.apple.security.network.client") when submitting it to Mac App Store?

Reference: [Documentation on enabling  App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW9)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does need that entitlement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12534354)

Comment: @Pbk1303 It does answer the question.  The question was phrased such that it warranted a *Yes* or *No* answer is *Yes* is the answer.  References to documentation is provided in the question itself, so there isn't much more to say in the answer.